# android stream handle, or how stop streaming

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I started streaming audio in my app, by MediaPlayer.

1. Pressing Play button and it starting streaming (music play)
2. I
   change activity or app
3. I am again call activity with buttons PLAY
   & STOP and STOP button NOT WORKING!

It happens because when I call activity again it initializing buttons from OnCreate.

How remember handle of playing stream and initialize buttons according to srteam status??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Mediaplayer(Streaming) then put the below code in OnDestroy

```
public void onDestroy() {
    if (player != null) { // if player is not null(Mediaplayer object)
        if (player.isPlaying()) { // if player isplaying than player stop.
            player.stop();
        }
        player.release();
        player = null;
        mActivity.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: In this case we will stop sound. if I need to continiue listerning sound but stop it by button from mainActivity when I back to my app?

Comment: i think one option you have to not any code add in - onpause and ondestry method

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
 if (player.isPlaying()) { // if player isplaying than player stop.
        player.stop();
    }

    player = null;
    finish();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should put the MediaPlayer in a Service to disassociate it from the life-cycle of the Activity. Once that is done, bind to the Service in onStart of your Activity as in the [example documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and call methods of the Service to interact with the MediaPlayer.